# Opencv : How to remove rectangle black box without removing any other characters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to remove a rectangle black box from the below image.

[image]

I do some preprocessing operation to keep the upper top of the image only. My problem with the rectangle in the middle of the image

This is the preprocessing operation I do on this image

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_top, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)




binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)


binary = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(binary, None, 65, 5, 21)


ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(binary, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

k = np.ones((4,4))
binary = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)
```

This is the output till now

[image]

Here it appears 3 lines connected together. I have used `cv2.findContours`. But till now I failed to remove this rectangle. I know I am doing something wrong regarding contours.

Here is the code I used for detecting contours

```
_,binary = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


# find external contours of all shapes
_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# create a mask for floodfill function, see documentation
h,w= image.shape
mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2), np.uint8)

# determine which contour belongs to a square or rectangle
for cnt in contours:
    poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.05*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(poly) == 4:
        # if the contour has 4 vertices then floodfill that contour with black color
        cnt = np.vstack(cnt).squeeze()
        _,binary,_,_ = cv2.floodFill(binary, mask, tuple(cnt[0]), 0)
```

how I can successfully remove this black rectangle without distorting letter **Q**

Comment: You can use `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` instead, see the answer below!

Comment: @ahmed osama It would be great if you can let people know what worked for you ansd share your insights how did you manage to remove the square boxes and the lines in [your example image](https://ibb.co/ekpZqT) ?

Answer (score 2):

I used `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` rather than `cv2.floodFill()`. Why?

I first found the contour having the highest perimeter and stored its points in a variable. I then used `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` to fill the contour of having highest perimeter with any color (in this case black `(0, 0, 0)` ).

**Code:**

```
_, binary = cv2.threshold(im, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('binary', binary)
```

[image]

```
#--- taking a copy of the image above ---
b = binary.copy()

#--- finding contours ---
i, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

im2 = img.copy()
max_peri = 0         #--- variable to store the maximum perimeter
max_contour = 0      #--- variable to store the contour with maximum perimeter

# determine which contour belongs to a square or rectangle
for cnt in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    print(peri)
    if peri > max_peri:
        max_peri = peri
        max_contour = cnt

#---- filling the particular contour with black ---
res = cv2.fillConvexPoly(b, max_contour, 0) 

cv2.imshow('res.jpg', res)
```

[image]

Comment: Very Good but when I try it with this image https://ibb.co/ekpZqT, I get a result that some letters are removed. How I can just remove the boxes and leave the letters.

Comment: @ahmedosama but this code was tailored for the image you posted :D I will try it out for this as well :)